# failed to build shared libraries with boost 1.48

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build boost 1.48 on an amd64 machine however shared libraries are not built due to a relocation error. Which I assumed due to `-fPIC` and that is the reason however could not fix that.

More specifically, here is what I get, with the boost from the trunk,

```
$ ./b2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a(codecvt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `vtable for std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried these

```
./bjam -d2
./bjam address-model=64 cxxflags=-fPIC
```

as explained/discussed here

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/fPIC-option-for-boost-td3176976.html

however did not help. I could not manage to build the shared libraries that I configure with `boostrap.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to build mosh-1.2.2 on a standard debian squeeze installation.  The following worked for me:

```
# cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5
# rm libstdc++.so
# ln -s ../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so
```

To explain in a more detail, the existing symlink was pointing to a non-existent file:

```
# cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5
# ls -l libstdc++.so
..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      23 May  3  2011 libstdc++.so -> ../../../libstdc++.so.6
..
```

I located the correct file location

```
# dpkg -S 'libstdc'
..
libstdc++6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
..
```

Then repaired the symlink as described in the first code segment.

The error I was getting during compiling was:

```
make[3]: *** [mosh-client] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a(functexcept.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `std::bad_typeid::~bad_typeid()' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

No idea how this particular debian squeeze server broke.  I've been compiling on other squeeze systems with no trouble.